# proxy error when downloading from public s3 bucket

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I'm new to s3 bucket, and I'm trying to unzip a file saved on a public s3 bucket. When doing this in R, my code is:

```
fn <- "http://s3://[redacted url address].tar.gz"
download.file(fn, destfile = "tmp.tar.gz")
```

I get either "500 Internal Privoxy Error", or "502 Fiddler - DNS Lookup Failed", depending on which computer I try it on.

I'm trying to search the internet for the right way to download from s3 bucket using R, but have not found much, hopefully I can get some help here.

thank you!

Comment: `http://s3://` can't possibly be right.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot - the url I have actually doesn't start with http but it doesn't work if I don't add http

Comment: Actually I'm just realizing now that there's a s3 connector in Python, and that might be what I will use, if there's no similar package in R?

Comment: Just take off the `s3://` before you add `http://`.

Comment: thanks Michael, I just tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try it from a web browser.  If it doesn't work there, the file in the bucket isn't actually "public."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially assumed that the redacted portion of `s3://[redacted url address].tar.gz` contained the fully-qualified hostname of the REST endpoint for the S3 bucket.

As it turns out, the format may simply be `s3://bucket-name/filename.tar.gz`.

In that case, you can still convert this to a downloadable URL (assuming the resource is public) ... the bucket name needs to be transformed to a hostname in S3.

```
s3://example-bucket/file.tar.gz
```

... becomes ...

```
http://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.tar.gz
```

If the bucket name does not contain any dots, then https will work as well.  (If there are dots in the bucket name, it still "works" but the `*.s3.amazonaws.com` wildcard certificate will not be trusted by an HTTP user agent.

All buckets with objects configured for public access are accessible via this URL format, from any web browser or other http user agent library.  S3 buckets are stored in one of several regions (specified by the bucket owner at bucket creation time) and each region has region-specific endpoints that also work, but the construct shown above is valid for all buckets.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region